# How to view the size of the parameters of a clients request in NetBeans(using Servlets)

Tags: servlets, netbeans

I want to view the size of the parameters in a clients request in NetBeans. Is there a built in facility to see this kind of info? I can view the actual parameter values, but not their size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.getHeader("content-length")`